# DIV & Animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, html

When i'm creating a menu with `DIVs` and animating it with `JS`, I found myself copying/pasting the same `JS` and `CSS` codes for every button of the menu.
Is there a way to create the animation `JS` code and the `CSS` style code once, and call them when needed for any button I may have on my website?

Answer (score 4):

Modularize your code by pulling the animation to a function and then apply it to all buttons (or anything) of a particular class. Like this:

Example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/9299P/

html

```
<button class="my-btn-class"></button>
```

css:

```
.my-btn-class {
  /* no stylings just a target*/
}
```

js:

```
  function myAnimation(btn) {
     //do stuff to btn
     $(btn).animate({
         opacity: 0.25,
         left: "+=50",
         height: "toggle"
     }, 5000, function () {
         // Animation complete.
     });
 }
     $(function () {
         $(document).on("click", ".my-btn-class", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             myAnimation(this);
         });
     });
```

you can paste your js animation inside the `myAnimation` function. that way every button with the class `my-btn-class` will do the same animation when clicked. It's a best practice to modularize code that you continue to reuse through out your site. This way that code can be easily maintained because it's all in once place.